# nginx config and error message

Tags: nginx

I believe I have an error in one of my nginx configs. I have tried:

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
* Restarting nginx nginx [fail] 
$
```

After some googling i then tried the following:

```
$ sudo service nginx -t
Usage: nginx {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status|configtest|rotate|upgrade}
```

but it only shows the list of commands. There are no messages about config errors in the nginx log or syslog. How i can get more detailed error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
nginx -t
```

i.e. when confronted with:

```
$ sudo su # if necessary
$ service nginx restart
* Restarting nginx nginx [fail]
```

Then use `nginx -t`:

```
$ sudo su # if necessary
$ nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "i" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:120
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: Nice, "don't drink and google". Need badge "drunk stupid question".